# Keep getting object has no attribute

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I came across one of Python feature which is called turtle. When I typed my codes according to the video, I keep getting this message: Turtle object has no attribute forward on line 3 but when I copy paste other codes on comment section which also have the same code and ran, those code didn't show this message eventhough i have the same code as those codes are, I already tried spacing, tab space but still the same message appear and I'm using window 7 64 bit with Python 3.5 32 bit

```
import turtle
my_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
my_turtle.foward(100)
my_turtle.left(90)
my_turtle.foward(100)
my_turtle.left(90)
my_turtle.foward(100)
my_turtle.left(90)
my_turtle.foward(10)
```

Comment: That should be **forward**.

Comment: Include the actual traceback. It likely says `foward`.

Answer (score 1):

You typed `foward()` instead of `forward()`, try the following:

```
import turtle

my_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
my_turtle.forward(100)
my_turtle.left(90)
my_turtle.forward(100)
my_turtle.left(90)
my_turtle.forward(100)
my_turtle.left(90)
my_turtle.forward(10)
```

Giving you:

[image: Turtle output]

Note: your final `forward()` is only `10` not `100`.